# Assign different colours to intersection between two polygons and difference area

Tags: r, polygon, ggplot2, fill, filling

I am quite new to GIS using R.

I have two sets of data, upon which I could create two polygons like this:
[image]

What I want to do is colour the common area (inner 'circle') and the space between borders. However, if I fill the two polygons directly, the colour for the outer polygon simply overlayed the inner polygon. Is there any way to do this nicely?
My codes are:

```
ggplot()+ geom_polygon(data = inter_Coords, aes(x = inter_Coords[,1], y 
= inter_Coords[,2],alpha = 0.25)) + 
geom_polygon(data = concave_pts, aes(x = concave_pts[,1], y = 
concave_pts[,2], alpha = 0.25)) +
geom_polygon(data = diff_Coords, aes(x = diff_Coords[,1], y = 
diff_Coords[,2], fill = 'yellow', alpha = 0.25))
```

Results are:
[image]

Comment: "What I want to do is colour the common area (inner 'circle') and the space between borders" - you seem to have done that, the common area is dark brown and the space between borders is light brown, unless I've misunderstood what you mean. Can you draw a picture of what you want and edit this into your question

Comment: The reason that the inner area is dark is that two same colors are overlapped. And I want the inner color to be, let's say, yellow and outer to be blue (two distinct color way)

Comment: So why are you setting alpha and making the colours transparent? Plot the larger one in blue then add the smaller one in yellow, don't set alpha to anything. You'll get a blue ring and a yellow inner polygon.

Comment: And take the fixed settings outside the `aes` call, ie like: `geom_polygon(..., aes(x=..y=..), col="yellow")`

Comment: There should also be a background image, which is tumor tissue. Set the transparency would make it easier to see which part of the tissue associated with the labeled area.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest solution is to use some of the geometric operators to construct the difference between the two objects. `sf::st_difference` or `rgeos::gDifference` depending on your data.